# Convert ISOdatetime to numeric and back

Tags: r, datetime

How to convert a numeric value, which stands for a ISOdatetime object back to POSIXlt? I tried the following but I dont know how to get the initial format of a.

```
a<-ISOdatetime(2013, 07, 22, 00, 00, 00, tz = "GMT")
b<-as.numeric(a)
class(a)<-c("POSIXct","POSIXt")
```

A other question is how to calculate with numeric date time? I would expect I get some day in the august.

```
 numericday<-as.numeric(ISOdatetime(2013, 07, 22, 00, 00, 00, tz = "GMT"))-as.numeric(ISOdatetime(2013, 07, 23, 00, 00, 00, tz = "GMT"))
 as.POSIXlt(b+20*numericday,origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
 as.POSIXlt(b+20*60*60*24,origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
```

Comment: `as.POSIXlt(a)` doesn't work?

Comment: It works sry If I typ as.POSIXlt(wochen,"GMT") but I tried as.POSIXlt(wochen,zt="GMT")

Comment: To set the timezone use `tz`, not `zt`.

Comment: sry I have a additional question to it, I edit my post

Comment: sry again, I thought it would work but it does not. so again why `a<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:30:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(a),origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")` both lines do not have the same result?